# Vector3: Variables as Coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Variables as Vector3 Coordinates...
This is part of a script on an empty game object that draws a quad and a ray.
I can draw a quad, and I can draw a ray.  I can move that ray around manually by typing floats into the Vector3.  Why can't I use  "planeWidth" or "planeHeight"  in place of digits in my Vector3?
I get errors just defining the  "public Vector3 rayA1Pos..." line.

```
//Define my Quad
    public float planeWidth = 24f;
    public float planeHeight = 34.5f;
//Declare rayA1
    private Ray rayA1;
    private RaycastHit hitA1;
    public float rayDistance = 150f;
//rayA1's Vector3 coordinate at top-right corner of Quad
 public Vector3 rayA1Pos = new Vector3( (**planeWidth**/2), (planeHeight/2), 0f);
```

Just to show an example of use, this works:
rayA1 = new Ray(transform.position + new Vector3(0f, 150f, 0f), transform.forward);

But why doesn't this work:

```
    rayA1 = new Ray(transform.position + rayA1Pos, transform.forward);
```

or this?

```
ray1 = new Ray(transform.position + new Vector3(planeWidth, planeHeight, 0f), transform.forward)
```

Once again, "planeWidth" and "planeHeight" are throwing errors when I place them inside as the Vector3 coordinates.
Thanks for reading.  This is my first pots, but I've been finding tons of cool stuff on this forum, so I already owe yall a big thanks! Tom G.

Comment: Hi! What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you are getting the following error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

You cannot use variables to initialize other variables the way you want in your global scope. You would have to change `planeWidth` and `planeHeight` to static. Normally you do the initialization in class constructors. In Unity3D with MonoBehaviour you usually do it in the `Start()` or `Awake()` method.

Do this instead:

```
public float planeWidth = 24f;
public float planeHeight = 34.5f;
public Vector3 rayA1Pos;

void Start()
{
   rayA1Pos = new Vector3((planeWidth/2), (planeHeight/2), 0f);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the error, and your recommendation has removed it!  So, it's a "scope" issue, above others?  Thank you.  I'm still having and issue getting the ray to originate from the right spot, but I wanted to let you know you have helped tremendously.

Comment: You could say it is a scope issue. Next time please remember to write the error message as it will help others to find the issue quicker. Glad I could help!